# Can pointers on std::type_info be compared for equality in constant expressions?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, constexpr, typeid

One can define a `constexpr` pointer on `std::type_info` object of any class `T`. Does the language allows one to compare such pointers for equality in compile-time?

For example:

```
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T>
inline constexpr auto * pType = &typeid(T);

int main() {
    static_assert( pType<int> == pType<int> );
    static_assert( pType<int> != pType<char> );
}
```

The question arises, since Clang accepts it, but GCC returns the error:

```
error: non-constant condition for static assertion
    8 |     static_assert( pType<int> != pType<char> );
      |                    ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:8:31: error: '(((const std::type_info*)(& _ZTIi)) != ((const std::type_info*)(& _ZTIc)))' is not a constant expression
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9broYrEn7

Comment: ["*The lifetime of the object referred to by the lvalue extends to the end of the program.*"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.typeid#1.sentence-2) This isn't *literally* static storage duration. What a peculiar way to describe this...

Comment: typeid isn't constexpr compatible (it has no constexpr variant) see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid. And even at runtime &typeid(T) == &typeid(T) is not guaranteed.

Comment: Try using typeid in consteval (C++20) you will see that it can never lead to a compile time only solution. The constexpr will compile to a runtime version in your example

Comment: This bug was fixed since GCC 12: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=103600

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a GCC bug: [85428](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85428)

By the way, `pType<int> == pType<int>` [is not always guaranteed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid#Notes).